# Why are the text labels in d3 transforming to zero on pan/zoom?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm fairly new at d3 and I've built the code from a couple of sources so it's probably just that I have it initializing incorrectly but I'm not seeing what it is. The page I'm building dynamically fetches geojson from a database and renders a simple map with a label. This works correctly but whe I added code to give the map zoom/pan functionality the map behaves correctly but the transform on the text moves the label to 0 postition with the `<g>` element and I'm not sure why? When I zoom in the map and text increases in size as expected but the text position stays at 0/0.

Instead of dumping a lot of code here I've put together this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rebel777/5ghuy6mc/10/) so that it could easily be seen and tested.

I think that anyone more familiar with d3 probably knows what I've got wrong here. I would sure appreciate someone pointing it out to me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See your problem saved in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrovinsky/5yv4820x/):

```
const items = g.selectAll('g.item')
  .data(bb.features)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .classed('item', true);

items.append('path').attr(...)

items.append('text').attr(...)
```

Instead of entering **path** and **text** elements separately, enter a **g** container and then append **path** and **text** under the **g**.